# Display issues (shadowing?) 14.04

Tags: 14.04, gnome

This is showed when i open software center,

[image]

Unreadable letters and description as you see, if i put focus on another program like this:

[image]

The letters become magically readable... what is happening? I'm a fairly new linux user who was previously a power windows user.
This happens with other programs like Firefox, when i load google.com the search textbox becomes 'shadow black' while the page isn't 100% loaded which returns to normal, youtube search box however you can't see what it's typed and the same thing happens on another sites.. (the YT box however doesn't become readable if i focus another window...)

Can someone help? I'm running a laptop with Intel Celeron and no dedicated graphics card.

(Sorry for the doubled images, i got double monitor setup)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a theme issue.  Try a different theme and see if the same thing happens please.

Comment: lol thanks a million, it was the GTK+ default theme (Adwaita) that was messing up, i had this problem for quite a while... i had tried to change "Window" theme in the same page of the gnome-tweak-tool... didn't think of changing GTK+ because i didn't know what it stood for... anyway, thanks again, recommend any specific themes btw?

Comment: You're welcome.  There are several themes in the repos, try installing some and see what you like best.